# Immunity Debuggger Inconsistent Results

Tags: debuggers

Question for people using Immunity Debugger.

Just started using Immunity Debugger, using 1.85 on Win 7 Pro.

Doing some labs on vulnserver.exe and I am getting inconsistent results from Immunity Debugger. I will attach vulnserver.exe, select run in IB and execute a script to crash vulnserver to analyze the output. Detach & restart vulnserver.exe, then attach again and run the same script. I get two different results in the output.

However, if I exit and restart Immunity Debugger between scripts, I get the correct output after running a script each time.

Is this standard behavior for Immunity Debugger? You have to exit and restart between each debugging capture?

I have re-installed IB twice and it continues to give these inconstant results.

TIA

Comment: what's IB? the results are different how exactly?

Comment: Sorry, IB = Immunity Debugger. If I keep Immunity Debugger open and attach & detach I will get various EIP values. However, if I open and close the Immunity Debugger application, I will get the proper (expected) result. It is as if it is perhaps caching information between each attach & detach? As long as I shut Immunity Debugger down and start it again, it works fine. It is just a little annoying to have to restart it over and over.